# Should my function to get an Android Contact by name return a Cursor or something else?

Tags: android

I'm working on a class that is supposed to handle the user's Android contacts and interact with an SQL database where you can move your phone's contacts to (the information in the database will be displayed as a ListView). I've made a function that is supposed to retrieve an Android contact by name and return all of that contact's information. My function is as follows:

```
public Cursor getContactByName(String name)
{
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = null;
    String selection = Data.DISPLAY_NAME + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{name};
    String sortOrder = null;

    return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}
```

So the idea is that this would be called by another function, which would first check if the contact existed. This function would return a cursor containing only that contact's information. First I want to know if I'm right in returning a Cursor containing the contact's information or should I instead create a class that stores this information and return an object of the class? Or perhaps I should return a string? Keeping in mind that what I'm returning is the contact that I intend to move to my database, I feel like returning a Cursor isn't what I should be aiming for. And as a side-question, is there any reason to use ContentResolver.query instead of managedQuery for my purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are going to be using the data for.  If you're going to be adding it to another database (as your question suggests) you are probably best off leaving it as a cursor and simply entering that cursor in your second database.  If you like mapping your database rows to objects, then do that.  Keep in mind Object Relational Mapping takes more memory and cycles but usually results in clearer code.  It's really up to you as the programmer (sorry I know that's not what you want to hear).

Comment: Okay, this answers my question. Thanks! Although, there is no problem with storing cursors this way, right? I can just grab the cursor from the database and get information from it like I would were I still handling it after creation? I'm really new to Android development, so cursors are still a little confusing to work with.

Comment: @Cheddar you used to have to worry about closing cursors, however I don't think that's as much of an issue now that cursors manage themselves.  You should be fine as long as you make sure to close the db connection once you are done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally i would prefer to create an object `Contact`. So you are more flexible and you can also implement functions related to your objects in this class (or the related DAO).
Passing the values as `Cursor` or even as `String` gives more trouble than it will help you. In an object you can see exactly the propertynames for everything, with a cursor you have to know the names or the positions of the corresponding fields, and in a string you even have to parse your results.

EDIT:
As @DavidCowden metioned, it depends strongly on what you are trying to achieve. So my guess was, that you want to load your data and display it somewhere.
And as already mentioned, in this case i would prefer a seperate class as it's much cleaner and maintainable.

Comment: Although using an object would be cleaner, I sort of worry about it taking more memory. A guy I'm working with this project on did an SMS database and returned SMSes as objects, but his XML page runs less than smoothly. Obviously SMSes would be more numerous than contacts, but would memory be an issue to worry about when returning the contacts as objects?

Comment: in your case i wouldn't worry about memory. There are no expensive calculations with doing some database querys to read contacts. And if i understood you right you only read one contat? I really think that it's much harder to work with cursors.

Comment: @Cheddar yes, as Obl Tobl suggests, memory should not be an issue.  Again, go for whatever is going to be the cleanest now and *optimize later* if required.